# lubridate fails when column contains both hms and ms

Tags: r, lubridate

I am cleaning a dataframe and trying to convert a column into hour:minutes:seconds using lubridate. The column has values in the formate of only minutes and seconds (e.g. "36:10) and some values have hours, minutes, and seconds (e.g. "1:06:32"). I can´t find a command in lubridate that doesn´t turn one of the two cases into NA.

Example below(I have added a row with NA values because my dataframe has several of these)

```
library(lubridate)
a <- c("36:10", "1:06:32", NA)
b <- hms(a)
b

[1] NA "1H 6M 32S" NA
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Or shorter with just base R:

```
a <- c("36:10", "1:06:32", NA)

a2 <- ifelse(nchar(a) < 6, paste0("00:", a), a)

hms(a2)

> hms(a2)
[1] "36M 10S"   "1H 6M 32S" NA
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not just paste on a "0:" if there is only one colon

```
hms(purrr::map2_chr(a, stringr::str_count(a, ":"), 
    ~dplyr::if_else(.y==1, paste0("0:", .x), .x)))
```